# IE 10 play video with no extension

Tags: internet-explorer, html5-video, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to play a video in IE 10:

```
<video id='media-player' controls preload='auto' width='1770' height='980' >
    <source src='file:///c:/file' />
</video>
```

This doesn't work. If I rename the file to file.mp4, it works.

The question is: how do I make IE 10 play the video, even if it doesn't have the mp4 extension?

Just as an idea, in IE 9 this worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `type="video/mp4"` to the `source` tag. Although, from what I know about the `audio` element, IE won't play the file if it does not recognize the extension, no matter what you try. I suspect this might be true with `video` as well.

Comment: Just curious - why do you need to omit the extension anyway?

Comment: pretty long story :) have to handle audio & video files, and I do not know what type is each, some configuration tells me that here you have to render video, here you have to render audio. I hard coded the .mp4 extension, but I would have loved if I could ignore the extension.